# QPushButton remove space (Jambi)

Tags: java, qt, qt-jambi, jambi

how can i remove the gap/space for `QPushButton`?

i'm looking at Windows 10 Calculator, which is:

[image]

as you can see there is no space between button 7 and 8, and i try to do the same thing in Jambi, by set the space for `QGridLayout` and `QPushButton` like so:

```
QVBoxLayout main_layout = new QVBoxLayout();

QGridLayout sample_layout = new QGridLayout();
sample_layout.setHorizontalSpacing(0);
sample_layout.setVerticalSpacing(0);
sample_layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
sample_layout.setSpacing(0);
sample_layout.setWidgetSpacing(0); 

main_layout.addLayout(sample_layout);

QLineEdit edit_input = new QLineEdit();

QPushButton action_0 = new QPushButton("0");
action_0.setMinimumHeight(60);
action_0.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

QPushButton action_1 = new QPushButton("1");
action_1.setMinimumHeight(60);
action_1.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

QPushButton action_2 = new QPushButton("2");
action_2.setMinimumHeight(60);
action_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

QPushButton action_3 = new QPushButton("3");
action_3.setMinimumHeight(60);
action_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

QPushButton action_4 = new QPushButton("4");
action_4.setMinimumHeight(60);
action_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

QPushButton action_5 = new QPushButton("5");
action_5.setMinimumHeight(60);
action_5.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

QPushButton action_6 = new QPushButton("6");
action_6.setMinimumHeight(60);
action_6.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

QPushButton action_7 = new QPushButton("7");
action_7.setMinimumHeight(60);
action_7.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

QPushButton action_8 = new QPushButton("8");
action_8.setMinimumHeight(60);
action_8.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

QPushButton action_9 = new QPushButton("9");
action_9.setMinimumHeight(60);
action_9.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

QPushButton action_plus = new QPushButton("+");
action_plus.setMinimumHeight(120);
action_plus.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

QPushButton action_minus = new QPushButton("-");
action_minus.setMinimumHeight(60);
action_minus.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

QPushButton action_divide = new QPushButton("/");
action_divide.setMinimumHeight(60);
action_divide.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

QPushButton action_times = new QPushButton("X");
action_times.setMinimumHeight(60);
action_times.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

QPushButton action_equal = new QPushButton("=");
action_equal.setMinimumHeight(120);
action_equal.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

QPushButton action_dot = new QPushButton(".");
action_dot.setMinimumHeight(60);
action_dot.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

QPushButton action_del = new QPushButton("< Delete");
action_del.setMinimumHeight(60);
action_del.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

QPushButton action_clear = new QPushButton("Clear");
action_clear.setMinimumHeight(60);
action_clear.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

sample_layout.addWidget(edit_input,0,0,1,4);
sample_layout.addWidget(action_minus,1,0);
sample_layout.addWidget(action_divide,1,1);
sample_layout.addWidget(action_times,1,2);
sample_layout.addWidget(action_del,1,3);
sample_layout.addWidget(action_7,2,0);
sample_layout.addWidget(action_8,2,1);
sample_layout.addWidget(action_9,2,2);
sample_layout.addWidget(action_4,3,0);
sample_layout.addWidget(action_5,3,1);
sample_layout.addWidget(action_6,3,2);
sample_layout.addWidget(action_1,4,0);
sample_layout.addWidget(action_2,4,1);
sample_layout.addWidget(action_3,4,2);
sample_layout.addWidget(action_clear,5,0);
sample_layout.addWidget(action_0,5,1);
sample_layout.addWidget(action_dot,5,2);
sample_layout.addWidget(action_plus,2,3,2,1);
sample_layout.addWidget(action_equal,4,3,2,1);
```

but i still getting gap in between.

[image]

Note: if i set `main_layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)` and `main_layout.setWidgetSpacing(0)` i get perfect fit for `QLineEdit` like image below, but not `QPushButton` so i believe there is an option in `QPushButton` that create this gap, but there is only on option for QPushButton `setContentsMargins()`, any idea?

[image]

i did look into others that asked the same question, they use `QSpacerItem` which the solution doesn't make sense (Doesn't feel like correct/professional way), cause in `QLineEdit` it does perfectly with out any gap, but not in `QPushButton`.

**Edit:** when i apply `action_plus.setFlat(true);` the button turn out to be look alike this:

[image]

Comment: I copy-pasted your code though I converted it to `PyQt` (but the end result is the same) and I have not spacing between the buttons at all. Also `QGridLayout` doesn't have `setWidgetSpacing()` (for both Qt4 and Qt5). I 've noticed that in your screenshot you also have a frame although you set the window to frameless mode. I run Linux and I have no frame (as the code suggests). Maybe the spacing is also some strange behaviour on Windows only? The buttons obviously have different styling by default (mine look like Win98 buttons more or less) so the spacing issue might be just because of Windows.

Comment: Btw is there a reason for `action_8.setMinimumHeight(defaultHeight);` instead of `action_8.setMinimumHeight(60);` like for all the other numerical buttons?

Comment: @rbaleksandar yeah, i was surprised that there is `setWidgetSpacing()` it show up in Eclipse and i used it(thought could help somehow, but didn't change anything). Jambi latest release is Qt 4.8.6, 
just now i was playing around with `stylesheet` if i change the background and border color, it fit perfectly! about stylesheet, do we have any option to invert the border? maybe as what you said is because of windows style.

Comment: If you want flat buttons simply use `your_button.setFlat(true)` and the result will be the same as in your screenshot of the Windows calculator. If that is what you mean by "invert the border".

Comment: oh, `defaultHeight` is an integer, so if i change one height all the button change as well, i forgot to change that, thought make the code look lesser.

Comment: So is the issue resolved? :)

Comment: @rbaleksandar i did for one `action_plus.setFlat(true);` whole button become transparency

Comment: let me screen shoot it

Comment: @rbaleksandar i updated the question (add the preview), what actually `setFlat()` does?

Comment: Flat means border is raised (the button seems to pop out of the surface it is attached to) if set to true. You should do some research explicitly on Qt under Windows 10 and how the styling of the UI components is affected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109728/discussion-between-rbaleksandar-and-bear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid a lot of writing create a custom class which inherits from `QPushButton`. Inside the constructor add a call `setFlat(true)` which is for handling the raising of the button's border (unless overridden with styles). The stylesheet below (use `setStyleSheet(...)` to set your button to use it) give a nice hover effect:

```
QPushButton:hover{
  background-color: rgb(164, 156, 156);
  border: 0px;
}
```

Change the colour to your liking to fit the Windows 10 theme. You can omit the `setFlat(true)` and instead add

```
QPushButton{
  border: 0px
}
```

to your stylesheet (along with the hover handler). The effect is the same.

The result is (on Linux in my case):

[image]

You can also flatten your `QLineEdit` using the `border` attribute in its stylesheet:

**No border at all:**

[image]

**1px solid border:**

[image]

Comment: @Bear Added some extra info for your line edit to make it fit the rest of the UI.